# How to bypass magic hooks when using hash or array elements

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use `Variable::Magic` in order to catch when an element of a hash is modified:

```
use Variable::Magic qw(cast wizard);
my %h = (a => 1, b => 2);
cast %h, wizard store => sub {
    warn "store: @_\n";
    my $k = $_[2];
    cast $_[0]{$k}, wizard set => sub {
        warn "$k set to ${$_[0]}\n"
    }
};
$h{a} = 33;
```

However, the second inner `cast` on the hash element will trigger the `store` magic from the hash, and go into an infinite recursion (and crash).

The only way I found around it was use the data attached via `cast` as a lock/flag:

```
use Variable::Magic qw(cast wizard);
cast %h, wizard
    data => sub {0},
    store => sub {
        return if $_[1]++;
        my $k = $_[2];
        cast $_[0]{$k}, wizard set => sub {
            warn "$k set to ${$_[0]}\n"
        };
        $_[1] = 0;
    }
;
$h{a} = 33;
```

That looks clumsy and dumb, and I feel like I be missing something obvious.

Is there any better method? I've looked for some option to `Variable::Magic::wizard` to `mask` its own magic in the methods, but I didn't find anything.

Note: I don't care to use the heavy-weight `tie` instead, or some other XS module that cannot be installed with a simple `apt-get`; if needs be, I can write my own XS where everything would be much simpler, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Tip: `return if $_[1]; local $_[1] = 1;` would be safer

Comment: Tip: Don't create a new wizard each time you call `cast`!

Comment: sure, that was to keep things short; especially for the inner `cast`, the key name could be passed as an argument to instead of via the closure: `cast $_[0]{$k}, $keywiz, $k;`, where `my $keywiz = wizard data => sub {$_[1]}, set => sub { warn "$_[1] <- ${$_[0]}" }`.

Comment: as to the unsafe `$_[1]++`, that's a bug, but better leave it as is, since that was a question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`store` is called when the hash element is fetched as an lvalue, so `$h{$k}=…`, `f($h{$k})` and `\$h{$k}` call `store`. So while `set` is called after the value is changed, `store` is necessarily called before it's changed.

In fact, it's called before the element is even fetched, so it's called before the element is even created when it doesn't exist. This is quite unfortunate, because it means than a simple `exists` check isn't sufficient.

Because the magic callback is called "at the wrong time" (when the element doesn't even exist), a solution like yours (i.e. using a flag) is the best I could devise.

That said, you should ensure that the flag is reset even if an exception occurs. This can be done using `local`.

---

Your goal appears to be to add some magic to each element of a hash, including those that will be created at a later time. To that end, I'd use the following:

```
use Variable::Magic qw( cast wizard );

my $hash_ele_wiz = wizard(
    set => sub {
        my ($ref) = @_;
        say "store: $$ref";
    },
);

my $hash_wiz = wizard(
    data => sub {
        my ($var) = @_;
        cast($_, $hash_ele_wiz) for values(%$var);
        return { nomg => 0 };
    },
    store => sub {
        my ($var, $data, $key) = @_;
        return if exists($var->{$key}) || $data->{nomg};
        my $ele_ref = do { local $data->{nomg} = 1; \( $var->{$key} ) };
        cast($$ele_ref, $hash_ele_wiz);
    },
);

my %h = ( a => 1, b => 2 );
cast(%h, $hash_wiz);

$h{b} = 3;          # store: 3
$h{c} = 4;          # store: 4
my $ref = \$h{d};
$$ref = 5;          # store: 5
```

It wouldn't take much to extend this to add the magic recursively. See the "Recursively cast magic on datastructures" recipe in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Variable::Magic).

Comment: since you turned the answer into a sample, it would be nice if you also passed the key name to the `set` method from the element wizard.

Comment: You'd pass it as an argument to `cast`, which would be passed to `data`.

Comment: I know that -- I already mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742480/how-to-bypass-magic-hooks-when-using-hash-or-array-elements/54744748?noredirect=1#comment96272657_54742480). My point was that it would be nice to add it to the answer.

Comment: The exact solution depends on the exact problem the solution is trying to address. Since the question is about a different problem, it lacks necessary information to provide an implementation. Trying to add this off-topic information to the answer will only reduce the clarity of the answer.

Comment: The gist of the answer is that `local` should be used instead of set/unset bracketing. *You* did transform it into a sample; feel free to reject, edit for style, whatever.

Comment: I rejected your edit. As I already mentioned when I refused to make it myself, there are issues with it. If the OP wants the key name to be used they'll have to provide information in their (forthcoming) question about whether they intend to use it on nested structures, and how they want to handle scalars that are found at mutliple keys.  (And `use strict; use warnings; use feature qw( say );` were left out because they just take up space for nothing.)

Comment: it doesn't matter if the same scalar/reference is set to multiple key, because the magic is per hash-element, not per-value. anyways, I have no intention to start a discussion, or act like I'm pleading something, so cheers!

Comment: I didn't say same value; I said same scalar. One of many ways of achieving this: `use experimental qw( refaliasing ); \$h{b}=\$h{a};`